# splitting and working with parts of array string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do a forEach process for each part of a split string object:

I am trying to create some code for each number character of a split string. An example of my string is as follows:

1,2,3,4;5,6,7;10;23,24

Where:

- the string does not necessarily start with "1".
- the string will only contain number characters.
- all the numbers after the first number are sorted, but not necessarily consecutive.
- there are different "teams" in the string, separated by ";"
- the teams can be as short as 1 character and as long as 31 characters.

The goal is to firstly separate the string into its teams and then iterate through each character of each team.

Here is what I have:

```
arr = "1,2,3,4;5,6,7;10;23,24";
//the above is a part of a larger string, already split, that is always different.
```

Now I can access the individual teams by:

```
arr1 = arr.split(";")[0]; //this should return "1,2,3,4"
arr2 = arr.split(";")[2]; //this should return "10"
```

The problem is that I cannot know how many "teams" the string contains, or how many characters each team contains, and I need to do something like the following:

```
x = 1;
$.each(arr + x, function(i, v){
    if(v!=","){
        //code here
    }
    x++;
});
```

Can someone please guide me in the right direction? Thank you, in advance.

Comment: `arr = 1,2,3,4;5,6,7;10;23,24;` assigns the value 1 to `arr`. I don't suppose that is what you intend. You write it is a string, but this isn't a string. The name `arr` suggests it is an array... So we have a number, a string, an array... What is it? Please fix that code.

Comment: Sorry if it is confusing. It is a string with the name "arr".

Comment: You should just make a full array of your daya: `arr.split( ';' ).map(v => v.split(',')).filter(team => !!team.length)`, which will be an `Array` of `Array`s, each containing all the team members in order, and filtered out the empty teams. You do not need jQuery for any of this, array come with this stuff built in.

Comment: Thank you trincot, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string represents a 2-dimensional structure: the first dimension is the team, the second dimension is the team member (an unsigned integer).

Here is how you would create a 2-dimensional array from such a string:

```js
const arr = "1,2,3,4;5,6,7;10;23,24";

const teams = arr.split(";").map(team => 
    team.split(",").map(Number)
);

console.log("there are", teams.length, "teams");
console.log("the first team's members are", ...teams[0]);
console.log("all the teams:");
console.log(teams);
```